# Error 1064 when executing an insert statement

Tags: php, mysql

I encounterd the following error while attempting to insert data into my table:

> [1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2','15','2013','12','5','51','PM','6','15','44','PM')' at line 2

I am using multiple check boxes in the form. How can I correct this error?

> error while inserting : [1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2','15','2013','12','5','51','PM','6','15','44','PM')' at line 2

I m using multiple checkboxes in the form

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="shree"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="order_people"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Get values from form


$first=$_POST['first'];
$last=$_POST['last'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$number=$_POST['number'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$address1=$_POST['address1'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$state=$_POST['state'];
$zip=$_POST['zip'];
$country=$_POST['country'];
$event=$_POST['event'];
$package=$_POST['package'];
$food_type=$_POST['food_type'];
$menu=$_POST['menu'];
$starters=$_POST['starters'];
$cold_drinks=$_POST['cold_drinks'];
$fast_food=$_POST['fast_food'];
$gujrati=$_POST['gujrati'];
$jain=$_POST['jain'];
$marathi=$_POST['marathi'];
$chinese=$_POST['chinese'];
$punjabi=$_POST['punjabi'];
$south_indian=$_POST['south_indian'];
$desserts=$_POST['desserts'];
$month=$_POST['month'];
$date=$_POST['date'];
$year=$_POST['year'];
$hours=$_POST['hours'];
$minutes=$_POST['minutes'];
$seconds=$_POST['seconds'];
$ampm=$_POST['ampm'];
$hours1=$_POST['hours1'];
$minutes1=$_POST['minutes1'];
$seconds1=$_POST['seconds1'];
$ampm1=$_POST['ampm1'];

$event = implode(",", $_POST['event']);
$food_type = implode(",", $_POST['food_type']);
$starters = implode(",", $_POST['starters']);
$cold_drinks = implode(",", $_POST['cold_drinks']);
$fast_food = implode(",", $_POST['fast_food']);
$jain = implode(",", $_POST['jain']);
$gujrati = implode(",", $_POST['gujrati']);
$marathi = implode(",", $_POST['marathi']);
$chinese = implode(",", $_POST['chinese']);
$punjabi = implode(",", $_POST['punjabi']);
$south_indian = implode(",", $_POST['south_indian']);
$desserts = implode(",", $_POST['desserts']);


// Insert data into mysql 
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name(first,last,email,number,address,address1,city,state,zip,country,event,package,food_type,menu,starters,cold_drinks,fast_food,jain,gujrati,marathi,chinese,punjabi,south_indian,desserts)
VALUES('$first','$last','$email','$number','$address','$address1','$city','$state','$zip','$country','$event','$package','$food_type','$menu','$starters','$cold_drinks','$fast_food','$jain','$gujrati','$marathi','$chinese','$punjabi','$south_indian','$desserts)";

echo ($sql);

$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='form.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo 'error while inserting : ['.mysql_errno().'] '.mysql_error();;
}
?>
```

SQL

```
INSERT INTO order_people(
    first,last,email,number,address,address1,city,state,zip,country,
    event,package,food_type,menu,starters,cold_drinks,fast_food,jain,
    gujrati,marathi,chinese,punjabi,south_indian,desserts
) VALUES(
    'Akshay','Desai','akshaydesai@mail.com','99846464','dihqwolhwoh','efhowhefop',
    'sifgoigfo','maharashtra','mumbai','India','Birthday Parties','1','Non-Vegetarian','',
    'Wontons Crab and Goons,Cucumber Mousse,Baked Shrimp Rangoon','Soft Drinks,Smoothies',
    'Aloo Tikki,Bhajiya,Bhel','Green Gram Dhokla,Jain Gawar Ki Sabji,Jain Spicy Sprouts Pulav,Jain Upma',
    'Stuffed Lady Finger,Surti Papdi Shaak,Dahi Vada,Singoda Na Bhajia','Chicken Biryani,Aloo Vadi,Bharli Vangi',
    'Chinese Noodles,Chicken with Brocoli and Rice,Chinese Veg Noodles','Aloo Amritsari,Chana Dal Paratha,Punjabi Kadi Pakoda,Punjabi Kadhi',
    '1,1','Fruit Dish,Coconut Pudding,Chocolate Banana Parfaits
)
```

error while inserting:

> [1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Fruit Dish,Coconut Pudding,Chocolate Banana Parfaits)' at line 2

Comment: Could you add the rest of your SQL query?

Comment: We cannot help you without seeing the code used to execute whatever SQL causes this error, or the full SQL which caused the error. My bet would be on a faulty `IN()` clause, however.

Comment: If you're adding dates and times into the database, there are much easier ways of doing it, by the way.

Comment: That is basic knowledge. Use Google to find out how to debug mysql queries. There are thousands of pages.

Comment: I m new on stackoverflow i want to post the code how I can do that ?

Comment: how to insert checked checkboxes data into mySQL in single column

Comment: @DesaiAkshay - There should be an Edit box by the question; echo the SQL query from your code, and copy and paste it into the question here.

Comment: I had pasted my sql code the all implode lines are for getting array of check boxes

Comment: @DesaiAkshay - that's your PHP code, not the SQL; could you also add an `echo ($sql);` just before the `$result=mysql_query($sql);` line, so we can see what SQL you're actually generating?

Comment: Please Check I had added it

Comment: @DesaiAkshay - you need to re-run your PHP. It will output a line of SQL before the error message, and that's what we need to see. It will start `INSERT INTO order_people(first,...`

Comment: @DesaiAkshay - thank you! You're missing the closing quote right at the end of your SQL statement. `'$desserts)";` should be `'$desserts')";`

Comment: I had added that echoed statement

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in building your query:

```
// Insert data into mysql 
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name(
  first,last,email,number,address,address1,city,state,zip,country,event,package,food_type,menu,starters,cold_drinks,fast_food,jain,gujrati,marathi,chinese,punjabi,south_indian,desserts)
VALUES(
  '$first',
  '$last',
  '$email',
  '$number',
  '$address',
  '$address1',
  '$city',
  '$state',
  '$zip',
  '$country',
  '$event',
  '$package',
  '$food_type',
  '$menu',
  '$starters',
  '$cold_drinks',
  '$fast_food',
  '$jain',
  '$gujrati',
  '$marathi',
  '$chinese',
  '$punjabi',
  '$south_indian',
  '$desserts
------------^
)";
```

You missed one `'` at the end. This should be:

```
  '$south_indian',
  '$desserts'
)";
```

By the way [**please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: I had error in my sql thank you all for helping me thanks a lot

Comment: Now code is working just fine

Comment: @DesaiAkshay Glad to hear that, do not forget to pay attention to the last part of my answer about `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: ya i will definetely learn PDO from your given link, thanks for your help j0k thank you very much :-)